# reconnecting issues in xmpp servers

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

i am using openfire xmpp server and asmack library to implement pubub node , the biggest issue that i face is the reconnection problem to the xmpp server.

whenever a connection is made to the xmpp server there are lots of stanza is being exchanged possibly around  5 to 7 stanza in a desktop applicaiton or web application it seems ok , but for mobile application where 3G link is pretty weak , in that case it too good to exchange so much of stanza.

i have tested that when the wifi has a weak signal or 3g link is down , i am making a reconnecting to the server (in background process) but i mostly get a response time out error and taking too much time if the connection gets successful.

i have seen messenger like whatsapp in which they are making a reconnection pretty fast. i want to do something like that only.

i have read about the pre-http binding but its exist in ejabber but didnt find anything in openfire moreover htt-prebinding is for anonymous users and i am using registered users only.

so can anyone tell me how can i reconnect fast to the xmpp server.

code snippet

```
    Boolean onlyConnect  = arg[0];

    try {



        if(xmpp!= null && !xmpp.isConnected())

        xmpp.connect();


    } catch(BOSHTimeoutException e){


        Log.e("XConnection " , "Timeout occures");

              // make a reconnection here



        return false;

    }


    catch(ConnectionException e){

        CatchErrors("ConnectionException" , "xmpp.connect()");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NoResponseException e){

        CatchErrors("NoResponseException" , "xmpp.connect()");

                // make a reconnection here


        return false;


    }catch (XMPPException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        CatchErrors("XMPPException" , "xmpp.connect()");

        e1.printStackTrace();

        return false;



    } catch (SmackException e) {

        CatchErrors("SmackException" , "xmpp.connect()");

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        CatchErrors("IOException" , "xmpp.connect()");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {




           Log.e("LOGIN REQUIRED " , "LOGIN IN");

     xmpp.login(XMPP_USER_NAME, XMPP_PASSWORD, "sh");



    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        CatchErrors("XMPPException" , "xmpp.login()");

        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    } catch(NoResponseException e){


         Log.e("LOGIN REQUIRED " , "NoResponseException");

        CatchErrors("NoResponseException" , "xmpp.login()");

        //make a reconnection here
        return false;


    }catch (SaslException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        CatchErrors("SaslException" , "xmpp.login()");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        CatchErrors("SmackException" , "xmpp.login()");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        CatchErrors("IOException" , "xmpp.login()");

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: its a whole scenario that i am currently facing and the code part is too large to share

Comment: I have add some of the code above

Comment: [XEP-0305 (XMPP Quickstart)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0305.html) contains some ideas for reducing the number of roundtrips when establishing a connection.

Comment: i am using pipelined request only so that part is already implemented

Comment: XEP-0305 has a bunch of recommendations that "pipelined request" doesn't cover, for example, implementing XEP-0198 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html).